# npm run typing error Windows_NT 6.3.9600

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-run

i am trying to  run the typings using below command

```
npm run typings -- install dt ~ core-js --save –global
```

i am facing the below errors.and struggling to understand to rectify this.please help with the solution.thanks in advance.

```
17 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "typings" "--" 
"install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "-global"
19 error node v6.10.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error @ typings: `typings "install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "-global"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ typings script 'typings "install" "dt~core-js" "--
save" "-global"'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     typings "install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "-global"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
23 error     npm bugs
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

Comment: `-global` should be `--global` 
 see https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md#install